# How to set Hibernate bulk_id_strategy in spring boot application?

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot, embedded-tomcat-8

Hibernate is generating temporary tables for TABLE_PER_CLASS inheritance but the prod. oracle user does not have those create table priviledges and therefore that approach is not an option for our project.

Hibernate Version 5.2.8 is said to resolve that issue. 
We updated our pom.xml accordingly to override default starter hibernate version setting.

**Still we dont have any luck with the following property.**

```
 <property name="hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy"
 value="org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.inline.InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy"
   />
```

APPLICATION PROPERTIES is also updated as follows

**

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1. :1521:
spring.datasource.username= 
spring.datasource.password= 
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy=org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.inline.InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy
```

**

Where is the proper location of this setting in a spring boot app?

The container is still generating temp tables in the test env. server startup.

kind regards

**pom.xml is as follows**

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<groupId>x.xx.ortakonline</groupId>
<artifactId>PolsanOrtakOnlineServer</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.0.RELEASE</version>

</parent>


<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <jjwt.version>0.7.0</jjwt.version>
      <hibernate.version>5.2.8.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>

        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>

    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.4.0</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope> test </scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
        <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
        <version>0.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: RDBMS oracle 11gR2

Comment: `spring.jpa.properties.<property-name-here>` is the correct format (notice the missing `properties` part in your configuration . Also adding that property to your pom is going to do basically nothing.

Comment: this did the trick for me. you could post this as the answer if you like.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> In addition all properties in `spring.jpa.properties.*` are passed through as normal JPA properties (with the prefix stripped) when the local `EntityManagerFactory` is created.

This comes from [the JPA section](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-data-access.html#howto-configure-jpa-properties) in the Spring Boot reference guide and, in a nutshell, explains how to pass additional provider specific properties.

Adding the following to your `application.properties` should do the trick

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy=org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.inline.InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by [M.Deinum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42803353/499052) above, you should add the following to your `application.properties` file:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.hql.bulk_id_strategy=org.hibernate.hql.spi.id.inline.InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy
```

and also add the following to the `properties` section of your `pom.xml` to override the bundled `hibernate-core` library. This is to ensure that the `InlineIdsInClauseBulkIdStrategy` class is found, as the class is only available in `Hibernate Core 5.3.1.Final` and above:

```
<properties>
        ...
        <hibernate.version>5.3.1.Final</hibernate.version>
</properties>
```